How do I code for a Shapiro Wilk test on a dataframe with 3 factor variables and one numeric variable in r?
Instead of isolating the dataset R dataset
into different groups according to group, sex and time and carrying out the S-W test on them individually, I'd like to get a table showing the various S-W results for the to the different  groups (group, sex, time) as can be done in SPSSSPSS table of normality test results
Tried this code:
shapiro_results <- engaged %>%
  group_by("group", "sex", "time") %>%
    summarise(shapiro_test = list(broom::tidy(shapiro.test(numeric_var))),
        .groups = 'drop') %>%
  unnest(shapiro_test)

